# Customize a number in numbered list - LibreOffice Writter

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have a numbered list in LibreOffice Writer like below:

```
1. xxx
2. xxx
3. xxx
```

How can I modify a single number in the list so it looks like below

```
1. xxx
2(A). xxx
3. xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to modify an individual number like that, but you can achieve the result by doing the modification outside of the built-in numbering function.  Here's an example:

[image: example]

I did it by limiting the automated number to just the digit (I deleted the period from the After separator):

[image: separator]

I eliminated the spacing following the digit:

[image: space]

And adjusted the tab stops in the ruler as seen in the first image (personal preference as to whether you want all aligned the same, with room for the (A), or modify individual entries to create extra space where needed).  I modified the indent on item 2 to reflect the example in your question.

The last step is to manually enter what you want after the digit.  For items 1 and 3, I typed a period, then a tab, which brings you to the start of the text.  For item 2, I typed `(A)`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The first image just shows a little text to visualize the alignment.  As a test, I added enough text for the paragraph to wrap to a new line.  The wrapped line was aligned with the start of the text on the original line.  If you want different indentation, you would need to adjust the settings.

Comment: well, the question is irrelevant now.  but maybe this answer will help someone.\